# Insert records across multiple databases in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am attempting to create a stored procedure to insert records from a table in one DB to another DB, using fully qualified names for each table, however, since the tables can be in different DB's, the DB name needs to be able to change based on where a field is located.  I attempted to set a variable and use the variable as the DB name, however, SQL does not allow this method.

Please supply me with any suggestions.

Below is a the query that I have to this point:

```
DECLARE @FromPractice varchar(5) = 'MCE'
DECLARE @ToPractice varchar(5) = 'CRRLL'
DECLARE @FromEnvironment varchar(5)
DECLARE @ToEnvironment varchar(5)

SET @FromEnvironment = ( select environment from practice where practice = @FromPractice)
SET @ToEnvironment = ( select environment from practice where practice = @ToPractice)


PRINT @FromEnvironment
Print @ToEnvironment

INSERT INTO [@ToEnvironment].dbo.Patinfo
(
 ---Fields
)
SELECT 
---Values
FROM [@FromEnvironment].dbo.PatInfo
where practice = @FromPractice
and pat_num = 25970
```

Comment: You can't use variable to identity object names. Do you need variables to know which database you are using? If so, you will need to use dynamic sql.

Comment: Yes I need variables to know which DB because I have to do a "prefetch" to see which DB i'm going to need. This is the "dynamic" I am referring to because the DB's used will, most likely, not be the same when the SP is ran.  I am currently looking into SQL Synonyms for a potential solution.

Comment: A synonym isn't going to help you here. Since you have to use parameters you will have to use dynamic sql. Do be very careful here as the approach for this requires some special attention to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Could you supply an example?  I have used dynamic SQL, however, I haven't used it for this type of example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough example of how you could do this in dynamic sql. Please note that this is vulnerable to sql injection. You need to add some logic in your process prior to this to make sure that you are safe. The easiest way given the nature of this is to check sys.databases for your environment variables. You are likely going to need those variable to hold more than 5 characters unless your database names are awfully short.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = 'INSERT INTO [' + @ToEnvironment + '].dbo.Patinfo
(
    --Fields
)
SELECT
--Values
FROM [' + @FromEnvironment + '].dbo.PatInfo
where practice = ''' + @FromPractice + '''
and pat_num = 25970'

--look before you execute
select @SQL

--When satisfied uncomment this
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I will attempt to do this on a small scale before using it on a large scale.

Comment: You are welcome. Make sure you test it and more importantly that you understand it.

Comment: @samyi that will definitely help with the table name. The dynamic sql also need to be parameterized for the where clause. I left the injection issues to the OP. :)